# keep :hover on dragging jquery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a site with an element where the CSS class has a :hover state showing an outline.
This works ok.
however:

1. When I start to drag this object (part of a sortable) the hover effect is removed, Jquery draggable doesn't keep the :hover state.
2. Once dropped, the css hover state won't reappear, I have to leave the object and reenter it to make the css effect appear.

Any way to solve these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class in your CSS declaration, like:

```
.object:hover,
.object.hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Add and remove the class inside your sortable by binding to start and stop, like:

```
$("#list").sortable({
    [..your other configs..],
    start: function( e, ui){
        ui.item.addClass('hover');
        ui.helper.addClass('hover');
    },
    stop: function( e, ui){
        ui.item.removeClass('hover');
        ui.helper.removeClass('hover');
    }
});
```

If you wanted to keep the hover class after drop, you might try this instead:

```
$(".object").mouseenter( function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover");
}).mouseleave( function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
$("#list").sortable({
    [..your other configs..],
    start: function( e, ui){
        ui.item.addClass('hover');
        ui.helper.addClass('hover');
    },
    stop: function( e, ui){
        // don't remove: ui.item.removeClass('hover');
        // don't remove: ui.helper.removeClass('hover');
    }
});
```

**See here in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9bvm63m4/**

Comment: nice and easy, I like it, I didn't added the second code as the first already adds the class to the helper too...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this kind of thing is implemented uniformly across browsers, so you'd probably run into different behaviour depending on which browser you use. Your best bet would be to add a CSS class to your element when you mouseenter, and remove the class when you mouseleave.